# React native - App crashing on start in Android after yarn add ffmpeg-kit-react-native

Tags: android, react-native, ffmpeg

I'm trying to install ffmpeg-kit-react-native into my app, but the app crash when I start it on my device.

The error log:

```
2022-01-04 11:02:19.754 6679-6728/com.indivibookvideo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
    Process: com.indivibookvideo, PID: 6679
    java.lang.Error: FFmpegKit failed to start on brand: Redmi, model: M2103K19G, device: camellian, api level: 30, abis: arm64-v8a armeabi-v7a armeabi, 32bit abis: armeabi-v7a armeabi, 64bit abis: arm64-v8a.
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:50)
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.NativeLoader.loadFFmpegKit(NativeLoader.java:189)
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegKitConfig.<clinit>(FFmpegKitConfig.java:145)
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegKitConfig.enableFFmpegSessionCompleteCallback(FFmpegKitConfig.java:864)
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.reactnative.FFmpegKitReactNativeModule.registerGlobalCallbacks(FFmpegKitReactNativeModule.java:168)
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.reactnative.FFmpegKitReactNativeModule.<init>(FFmpegKitReactNativeModule.java:135)
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.reactnative.FFmpegKitReactNativePackage.createNativeModules(FFmpegKitReactNativePackage.java:37)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactPackageHelper.getNativeModuleIterator(ReactPackageHelper.java:42)
        at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:42)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:1347)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackages(ReactInstanceManager.java:1318)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1240)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1100(ReactInstanceManager.java:131)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1023)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "av_log_default_callback" referenced by "/data/app/~~ND_-wXIgMVuMMF9lccD4sg==/com.indivibookvideo--UwQec7E4IjmttOF7QiG9A==/lib/arm64/libffmpegkit.so"...
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:48)
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.NativeLoader.loadFFmpegKit(NativeLoader.java:189) 
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegKitConfig.<clinit>(FFmpegKitConfig.java:145) 
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegKitConfig.enableFFmpegSessionCompleteCallback(FFmpegKitConfig.java:864) 
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.reactnative.FFmpegKitReactNativeModule.registerGlobalCallbacks(FFmpegKitReactNativeModule.java:168) 
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.reactnative.FFmpegKitReactNativeModule.<init>(FFmpegKitReactNativeModule.java:135) 
        at com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.reactnative.FFmpegKitReactNativePackage.createNativeModules(FFmpegKitReactNativePackage.java:37) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactPackageHelper.getNativeModuleIterator(ReactPackageHelper.java:42) 
        at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:42) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:1347) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackages(ReactInstanceManager.java:1318) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1240) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1100(ReactInstanceManager.java:131) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1023) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
2022-01-04 11:02:19.770 6679-6724/com.indivibookvideo E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2022-01-04 11:02:19.853 6679-6679/com.indivibookvideo E/SensorManager: Qcd unregisterListenerImpl, by:com.facebook.react.common.ShakeDetector
```

Comment: Hey @B. Mohammad, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Mizzy i did not use it after all.